# Automatic cleaning of polygon overlap based on attribute in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, geometry, topology

I have a shapefile with overlapping polygons. I need to clean these overlaps based on an attribute: in case of polygon overlap, the polygon with the *lowest* value of a given attribute needs to be clipped, while the polygon with the *highest* value of attribute remains the same. Any idea?

Ideally I'm searching for an automated solution with a plugin or a script. However my dataset is not really big (around 20 shp with about 50 features each and three different values of the attribute; no need to clear overlap between different shps), so manual work would also be ok, but which tool would be the most efficient in this case?

PS: [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155735/assigning-overlapping-polygons-based-on-attribute-using-arcgis-for-desktop) could be a possible solution, but I don't have access to arcGIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**QGIS 3.2**

You can follow the same workflow you have linked.

(1) **Union** breaks the overlapping polygon into parts.

(2) **Delete duplicate geometries** will remove overlapping parts, while retaining only one geometry which is listed at the top on the attribute table. (Sort the attribute table by **Order by expression** tool beforehand).

(3) **Dissolve**

Only difference from the ArcGIS workflow is that you do not have to export each duplicated feature separately.

Comment: my overlaps are in _one_ shapefile... is there a way to perform union in just one shapefile?

Comment: @almerillat If you mean single shapefile layer, yes, it does the job. For the details of this new **union** tool see [Changelog QGIS 3.2](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog32/#feature-union-algorithm-with-a-single-layer).

Comment: Oh, my bad. I didn't see that your answer only works in QGIS 3.2. I'm stuck with QGIS 2.18 at work, I will try it on QGIS 3.2

Comment: I stumble upon the "delete duplicate geometries". How can I order the attribute table by expression? I tried a few things (sort the attribute table by a field by clicking on it or right-click and sort...) but they don't seem to work. The "delete duplicate geometries" tool deletes one of the two features seemingly randomly.

Comment: @almerillat **Order by expression** tool can be found in the `Processing Toolbox |  Vector general`.